# How to convert barcode to base64 format

Tags: barcode

I tried to create a barcode and convert that to base64 using the below code.

But it throws

> "javax.imageio.iioexception: can't read input file!"

while converting that to base64.

It was working properly in 1 server. When we migrated to another it didn't

```
String baseUrl = "";
                    Long rbCode = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(EmployeeMasterQueryUtil.maxRBCode, Long.class);
                    String sPath = bCodeServerPath + "/" + rbCode + ".png";
                    String imgUrl = bcodeLocalPath + rbCode + ".png";
                    BarCode.createCode(rbCode, imgUrl);
                    Base64 base = new Base64();
                    try {
                        baseUrl = base.base64(bcodeLocalPath, sPath);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Barcode is converted

Comment: Wouldn't you want to run the base conversion on the image file (imgURL)?

Answer (score 0):

It is working now. I had to change the url.